# I'd like to say a [word] or two about this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a tag: [word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word)

I see no value in this tag. Here's from the wiki:

> #### Use this tag for:
>
> - Challenges involving generating words
> - Challenges involving using words
> - Challenges involving manipulating words
>
> Or other cases where words are a large part of the challenge.
>
> #### Do not use this tag for:
>
> - Challenges based on printing a *predefined* string, e.g. "Hello, World!" challenges.
> - Challenges where the input or output are words, but it doesn't add much to the challenge.

I think this tag is extremely broad, and not helpful at all. Can you be an expert in words? *Sure*, you can, but not in the context of a programming <s>Q&A site</s> challenge site.

This is pretty much a subtag of [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), seeing as how challenges involving *words* are usually challenges about strings that just so happen to also be words.

However, specific tagging is never a bad thing, and most of the [word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) challenges have one thing in common. They're about language processing. For example:

- [Generate a pronouncable word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11877/31716)
- [Is this even a word?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45295/31716)
- [What language is this word?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71078/31716)
- [Word or near-word?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73344/31716)

The [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) tag is for

> Problems involving processing of natural languages in a human way. Task such as interpreting free text, correcting spell or grammar, understanding pronunciation etc.

Most of these word challenges are *also* about processing natural languages in a human way. The few that aren't are just adding extra noise.

**TL;DR** Let's merge [word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) into [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree, [word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) should become [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language). We could either retag the current 26 challenges bearing that tag (not all at once) or make [word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) a synonym of [natural-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language). I propose we do the latter.

---

**Note:** To vote on the proposed synonym, go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/natural-language/synonyms).

Comment: I didn't think I had enough points to suggest a synonym, but apparently I have 8 points in [natural-language]. Who knew? :P Anyway, I have already suggested this synonym, now we just need more people to vote.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ Looks like only people with sufficient rep in the tag can vote on the synonym proposal. +1 from me.

Comment: If too few people have the requisite reputation to vote but there's a lot of support for this synonym, I can just auto**mod**ically do it, but Ham DJ won't get a badge.

Comment: No! Mah badge! Haha, I didn't even realize there was a badge for that. How about we wait a little while (A couple days? A week? idk) and see if the votes come about naturally or if any alternate opinions pop up.

Comment: Is there a way to check how many people have the requisite 5 net score needed to vote on the synonym? Given that there are no bronze badges for [tag:natural-languages] awarded yet, I'd suspect the number might be low enough to warrant a mod action (since the synonym proposal has strong support, going off of this answer's votes).

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ Yeah, I'd say let's give it time. If it hasn't amassed the requisite votes in a week or so then I can go ahead and do it if that's alright. It's still at one vote (mine). :/

Comment: @Mego I don't know of an easy way to find that out. I think there *are* enough people, it's just a matter of getting them to notice. For example, you can view the top users in the tag [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/natural-language/topusers).

Comment: There are 20 people with the requisite 5 net score. In order to get +4, 20% of the people with the requisite score will need to vote it up. Considering that only 17% of eligible voters voted in the moderator election, I'm not confident that we'll get enough votes on the synonym.

Comment: @Mego Nice static analysis! Er, I mean statistic analysis. Either way, it's at +3 now. :P

Comment: Official update: The synonym proposal has gotten enough votes. And also: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/synonymizer?userid=31716

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ Nice! Congrats on the badge and thanks for taking the initiative on this.